Yasnippet not working properly in Latex but works in other Modes
As the title says, when I am editing a LaTeX document I cannot do yas-expand. Note that yas-insert-snippet works fine (although also here the shortcut does not work, I have to call it using M-x 'yas-insert-snippet').
On the other hand, when editing my .emacs file I can simply write if followed by  and it automatically expands to (if t) as defined in the snippets.
Update:
Removing ~/.emacs.d and restarting emacs (and consequently all packages) seems to have fixed the issue.

Try to come up with a recipe telling others how to reproduce this behavior.  Something like: Start Emacs with emacs -Q, then eval this  in the scratch buffer: (progn (setq debug-on-error t) (package-initialize t) (package-activate 'auctex) (package-activate 'yasnippet) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (yas-reload-all) (yas-minor-mode)))) and then open a .tex file (presuming that you have installed both packages from ELPA).
